"Stuck" Transaction Locking a Table MariaDB InnoDB
I am getting a lot of wait lock time outs on one of my tables when running some updates. I checked INNODB_LOCKS, INNODB_LOCK_WAITS, and SHOW PROCESSIST and I could not see anything. I ran SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_trx ORDER BY trx_started. Here are my results:
| trx_id     | trx_state | trx_started     | trx_requested_lock_id | trx_wait_started | trx_weight | trx_mysql_thread_id | trx_query | trx_operation_state | trx_tables_in_use | trx_tables_locked | trx_lock_structs | trx_lock_memory_bytes | trx_rows_locked | trx_rows_modified | trx_concurrency_tickets | trx_isolation_level | trx_unique_checks | trx_foreign_key_checks | trx_last_foreign_key_error | trx_is_read_only | trx_autocommit_non_locking |
|------------|-----------|-----------------|-----------------------|------------------|------------|---------------------|-----------|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|------------------|-----------------------|-----------------|-------------------|-------------------------|---------------------|-------------------|------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|----------------------------|
| 2429970430 | RUNNING   | 9/23/2024 11:22 | NULL                  | NULL             | 8          | 0                   | NULL      |                     | 0                 | 1                 | 6                | 1128                  | 6               | 2                 | 0                       | REPEATABLE READ     | 1                 | 1                      | NULL                       | 0                | 0

That Transaction has been running since I last restarted the server. Is there anyway to just roll back this transaction or even delete it. I have backups of the table data integrity is not that important.

There's a KILL statement, if that's what you're asking.

The issue is there is nothing to kill. This transaction came back after a restart.

"came back" -- Perhaps it is doing a ROLLBACK.

I was able to solve this issue by using the steps in this AWS Knowledge base article combined with Maria DB XA Transaction specifics. Here are the steps I did:

To identify the XA transactions that are in the PREPARED status, run the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS command.
Example output:
---TRANSACTION [2043536230](tel:2043536230), ACTIVE (PREPARED) 302510 sec recovered trx  
 9 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 7 row lock(s), undo log entries 1  
 ---TRANSACTION [2043368758](tel:2043368758), ACTIVE (PREPARED) 303628 sec recovered trx  
 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 2`

Note: XA transactions don't appear in SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST.

Run the XA RECOVER command in Command Line.
Example output:
mariadb> xa recover;  
     formatID  gtrid_length  bqual_length  data                                   
             1            35             1  3d36dccd-61d0-4ae1-9b39-f9ccc2400d44:44       
             1            43             2  11740f2a-8a85-4b33-b924-982c1539d197:2222 `

Note: Each XA transaction begins with a XA keyword followed by the XA transaction identifier (XID). An XID has three parts:

The gtrid is a global transaction identifier.
The bqual is a branch qualifier. This value must be different for each XA transaction within a global transaction.
The formatID is a number that identifies the format that the gtrid and bqual values use.

For more information on gtrid, bqual, and formatID, see XA transaction SQL statements on the MySQL website. For MariaDB Here

Run the XA RECOVER FORMAT='SQL' command to get the data in a human readable form that can be directly copy-pasted into XA COMMIT or XA ROLLBACK
Example output:
 mariadb> xa recover format='SQL';  
 formatID  gtrid_length  bqual_length  data                                       
         3             11             2  X'31320d3334093637763738',X'6162630a646566',3    
 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


Run the XA ROLLBACK or XA COMMIT command to roll back or commit the XA transactions. Use the preceding method to break down every XA transaction that requires a rollback. Which looks like this:
 mariadb> xa rollback X'31320d3334093637763738',X'6162630a646566',3 ;




Perhaps you could add some details from those links to the answer itself, lest it become useless once the links rot.

Thank you for the feed back. That was a very good point. I updated my reply. I'm very new to this.

XA -- are multiple computers involved??

Yes. Still working on tracking down the root issue. But its a low priority since I'm moving off Maria DB.
